# Is the Functor "preservation of composition" law just distributivity?

Tags: category-theory

I'm a software developer who's in a little too deep, so bear with me.

The [definition of a Functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Definition) reads:

> [...] such that the following two conditions hold:
>
> - [...]
> - $F(g\circ f)=F(g)\circ F(f)$ for all morphisms $f : X → Y$ and $g : Y → Z$ in $C$.
>
> That is, functors must preserve [...] composition of morphisms.

After staring at this for a bit, I realized that this looks simply like "$F$ distributes across composition ($\circ$)". It seems to fit the [*left distributivity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Definition) property perfectly*. Am I correct in this observation?

In functional programming, $F$ is just a function called `map`, and $\circ$ is just `compose`, and I don't see why the law of distributivity between those needs a special definition. But I can imagine that perhaps in the underlying category theory, $F$ and $\circ$ don't live in the same realm or something.

---

* I might also just be using an overly liberal/generalized definition of left distributivity. I thought, since $n$ repeats in $n * (a + b) = n * a + n * b$, it doesn't need to be in there: $f (a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$. So I figured it applies just as well to unary operations.

Comment: It’s ultimately a matter of terminology, but the word “distributivity” is (generally?) reserved for binary operations. In particular, all elements should come from the same universe, unlike in your case where we apply a functor to morphisms. It’s more natural to think of this property of a functor like a “homomorphism” (i.e. structure-preserving map) between categories, and we would say it preserves, or is compatible with, the composition.

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

Comment: @Milten I don't think "distributive" is reserved for binary operations. For example, one sometimes says that inverses distribute over a given operation. Here the inverse is a unary operation. 
I agree with your sentiment that the functorial law is a generalization of a homorphism. But isn't distributivity also expressing that some operation is a homomorphism of another? For example, in a ring, the distributive law $a(b + c) = ab + ac$ expresses that left multiplication by an element is a homomorphism of the underlying group.